# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ID file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I know this question is asked several time, but unfortunately I am asking it again as I am not getting its solution. I am trying to solve this error from last few couple of days and I am unable to solve this.

> Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMSTests.xctest/QMSTests normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/admin/Documents/iPhone Apps/Divya/QMS"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Intermediates/QMS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMSTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QMSTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMS.app/QMS -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Intermediates/QMS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMSTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QMSTests.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Intermediates/QMS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMSTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QMSTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMSTests.xctest/QMSTests

ld: file not found: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QMS-cacudjkdofhyczasnkiyzjzfwjpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMS.app/QMS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me,tell me the way how can I solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have moved the folder from one mac to another.
Old references are not finding the file.
The files which have not been detected, should be showing in RED Font color in project navigator (on the left side of xcode).

Try adding these file manually by just dragging the files directly to your project navigator.

Comment: The file is <ProductName>Test.xctest. I mean the error takes me to this file under Product group.

Comment: Check other linker flags in build settings and add $(inherited) to it.|

If it doesn't work, go and delete derived data.

From x-code->Preferences->location->Click on the arrow after derived data location.

Delete all of it.